# Thunderbird 115 not working

Tags: email

Recently, Thunderbird updated to 115.3.1 when I wasn't looking. Sudenly there's a new icon, but also a new problem. The problem is that it can't download emails from my mail server. The server does not recognize my password, even though I've typed it in innumerable times.

Any help?

ETA: Here's all the lines from the error console

```
NotFoundError: No such JSWindowActor 'DevToolsFrame' 4
Missing resource in locale en-CA: devtools/client/toolbox.ftl
Missing resource in locale en-GB: devtools/client/toolbox.ftl
mailnews.pop3.3: Socket state is closed - won't send command. 17 Pop3Client.jsm:487:22
mailnews.pop3.1: NetworkTimeoutError: a Network error occurred 4 Pop3Client.jsm:369:18
mailnews.pop3.5: Socket state is closed - won't send command. 4 Pop3Client.jsm:487:22
mailnews.pop3.5: NetworkTimeoutError: a Network error occurred Pop3Client.jsm:369:18
```

Comment: I didn't change anything. I didn't even try to update Thunderbird. It happened all on its own. The password is one that I've used for years.

Comment: Did it suddenly start prompting for a password and never did before? What is the **exact** text of the error message?

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I don't have my passwords saved by the system, so every time I reboot, I have to type the password in again. If I make an error doing so, some long time (one to two minutes) later it cames back with an error and I have to retype. It was the exact same error message as that. As far as logs go, let me know which ones you want and I'll post. Be sure to include the complete path, since I probably don't know where they are.

Comment: You can turn on loggng (see: [Logging mail sending in Thunderbird](https://thunderbirdtweaks.blogspot.com/2021/10/logging-mail-sending-in-thunderbird.html))   (Please read the complete text, and do **not** post an IMAGE of this logging, but only TEXT, which makes it easier to change your email address to something like '********'

Comment: The log has only a few entries. I suspect the key one is "mailnews.pop3.3: Socket state is closed - won't send command."

Comment: Please use [edit], and add all lines (anonymized, if needed) of 1 session to your question.

Comment: I would focus on "a Network error occurred"   Why would Thunderbird not be able to connect to your mailserver?

Comment: "*Socket state is closed - won't send command*" means that the mailserver is not listening for your connection. Talk to whomever runs your mailserver.

Comment: Problem solved. Turns out that I didn't have an email recovery phone number in place at the mailserver and it was rejecting attempts to log in because of that. It was just a coincidence that this happened at the same time that Thunderbird was updated.